# setting environment int variable in Linux for use in a while loop in python but loop doesn't stop

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I'm controlling a LED on a raspberry pi 2 with Python. I want the LED to go on for x seconds. When I set an environment variable in Linux. For example, `export t=5`. The LED goes on but won't go off.

If I just set the variable in the python script everything works fine.

I'm setting an environment variable in Linux like so:

```
export t=5
sudo python test.py
```

And getting it in Python like so:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python

    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
    import time
    import os


    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

    GPIO.setup(11,GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

    GPIO.setup(12,GPIO.OUT)

    GPIO.output(12,0)

    s = 0

    t = os.environ.get('t')

    while s <= t:
            if (GPIO.input(11) == 1):

                            GPIO.output(12, 1)

                            time.sleep(0.1)

                            s += 0.1
            else:
                    GPIO.output(12, 0)

    GPIO.output(12, 0)
```

Comment: Add some debugging print statements to your loop. What is the value of `t` and `s` at each loop? Does `s` exceed `t` as some point but the loop keeps going?

Comment: Already did. and i saw the t variable counting endless

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The values of environment variables — and thus the values of `os.environ` — are stored as strings.  Thus, you need to convert `t` to a number in order for comparison with `s` to do what you want:

```
t = int(os.environ.get('t'))
```

Comment: Awesome that did the trick! thanks! dind't know that all environment variable's were stored as strings.

Comment: @Julez If you mean in the shell the export for `t` does not need the quotes. The shell doesn't distinguish that way.

Comment: Yeah noticed that.. was a mistake from me. i removed that part from my answer.